# How to set color resource as a wallpaper in android?

Tags: java, android, colors, drawable, android-wallpaper

I want to set a solid color as a wallpaper in android, but when I click on the button, the app unfortunately stops.

**Here is my code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wm.setResource(R.color.red);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Here is the code of colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff4366</color>
</resources>
```

**Logcat:**

```
10-24 15:59:26.216  12529-12529/com.danish.testapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
10-24 15:59:26.216  12529-12529/com.danish.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.danish.testapp, PID: 12529
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1271)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1241)
            at android.app.WallpaperManager.setResource(WallpaperManager.java:739)
            at com.danish.testapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have also set the required permissions in the manifest.

Comment: post you logs and all the code of this class

Comment: updated the questions... check it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WallpaperManager you must set drawable.

```
wm.setResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Edited

also you must set permission.

```
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
```

for set color with drawable you can using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/your_coloe" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Edited

Finally Resolved:

I Writing a sample. it' worked. enjoy it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable);
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "bitmap = " +bitmap);
        try {
            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }



    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to set the solid color as wallpaper such as #ff0000... hope you getting it ??

Comment: errors gone...toast msg showing up but wallpapers not changing...:(

Comment: thanks man. you have no idea how much you have helped me... thanks a lot...:)

Comment: i am not able to vote up. i need 15 reputation to vote up till now i have 10.

Comment: When using single color bitmaps of 1x1 pixel to set the Android wallpaper seems to crash the device and require factory reset, for example on Meizu devices. Any idea why?

Comment: @Jamrelian i don't no, it's very bad & amazing :(

Comment: `getResources().getDrawable` Deprecated use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.wallpaper, null);` instead